# Копировать текст из DOM элементов в буфер обмена

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

Есть разметка, содержащая текстовую информацию:

```html
<div class="text_row">
  <div class="name _copy">телефон</div>
  <div class="value _copy">+7 902 990 1812</div>
</div>
<div class="text_row">
  <div class="name _copy">e-mail</div>
  <div class="value _copy">zhdankov@akrk.info</div>
</div>
<div class="cntrl">
  <p>ctrl+c</p>
</div>
```

Нужно, при нажатии на кнопку, скопировать содержание блоков в буфер обмена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найти элементы и получить текстовое содержимое, трудностей не составляет. Также, как и [копирование в буфер обмена](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API). Одна загвоздка - здесь, в сниппете, это не проверить, ибо [запрет](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes). Пример только отобразит в консоли то, что будет скопировано, но на реальном сайте всё должно сработать:

```js
const copyBtn = document.querySelector('.cntrl > p');
copyBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let copyData = [...document.querySelectorAll('._copy')].map(el => el.textContent).join('\n');
  if (copyData) {
    console.log(copyData);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyData);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="text_row">
  <div class="name _copy">телефон</div>
  <div class="value _copy">+7 902 990 1812</div>
</div>
<div class="text_row">
  <div class="name _copy">e-mail</div>
  <div class="value _copy">zhdankov@akrk.info</div>
</div>
<div class="cntrl">
  <p>ctrl+c</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @RustySPC: не знаю, насколько это универсально - с буфером обмена разрабы браузеров постоянно что-то мутят.

Comment: В любом случае, оно работает. Да и мне сегодня отдавать проект, а после-  пусть горит оно огнем)